# groff ms indentfirst and frenchspacing

Tags: text-processing, groff

I am typesetting drafts of my papers with the `ms` macro package, but in my language (Spanish) the custom is to indent all paragraphs and keep space regular after a period, contrary to US custom to noindent the first paragraph after a heading or a quotation and adding a space after a period. What is the `ms` equivalent to the TeX construct `\usepackage{indentfirst}` or `\frenchspacing`, to make the settings global?

Comment: If you're using `.PP` to start a paragraph, it should be indented. Could you show an example?

Comment: I meant to say something akin to `\usepackage{indentfirst}`, which makes the change global for the document, and not on a paragraph by paragraph basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing what a paragraph is in troff. Unlike TeX, in troff a blank line is not a paragraph separator, it is a blank line on output. If you want to start a paragraph you have to use a command, `.PP` in your case, if you want an indented paragraph, or `.LP` for an unindented one, *explicitly*. You can see this in the following output, where the first two blocks of text each begin with a `.PP`, but the following line beginning `Hi!` was just separated by a blank line:
[image: troff]

Therefore, there is no way to set automatic paragraph indentation, as all paragraph marks must be explicit.

You can also see a difference in the vertical spacing as the paragraph spacing used register `PD` which I set to 0.5 of a line height, whereas the blank line produced a full height vertical space.

On the contrary, the last 2 lines show the result of applying the command:

```
.ss 12 0 \"N M: space size N/12*width(space). sentence space size M/12
```

between the 2 lines. The `.ss` command is described in `man groff_diff`, as setting interword and intersentence spacing. The default is `12 12`, and setting `12 0` removes the extra between-sentence spacing, which applies to `.` as well, of course.

Comment: The `.ss` request did its job. As for the other question, I was fully on the wrong track, using `.LP` instead of `.PP` after some constructs, such as `.NH`, just by blind cargo cult writing.

Comment: You should click on the tick next to the answer so others know at a glance it was accepted. Also, you may get faster answers if you stick to one problem per post, as some may not want to answer if they don't have all of the solution.